# How to use a csv with header for sagemaker batch transform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-science, amazon-sagemaker, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I am performing a sagemaker batch transform using a transformer created out of an xgboost estimator. The csv input for prediction/batch transform has both, an ID column and a header (with names of columns). For example, something like this:

| Name | Age | Height | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | 10 | 2 | 3 |
| John | 20 | 3 | 4 |
| Jane | 30 | 4 | 5 |

Of course, what needs to be passed is just the model inputs without the index (in this case, Name) or header (first row)

We can exclude the index (i.e. 0th) column by using the InputFilter argument when creating the job as follows:

```
DataProcessing = { 
      "InputFilter": "$[1:]"}
```

My question is how do we exclude the header? What JSONPath can be used for that?

Answer (score 1):

CSV format doesn't seem to support headers so don't think there's a path that'll help here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/cdf-training.html#cdf-csv-format